# Test if one forecast outperforms all other

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, accuracy, diebold-mariano-test

I have 4 different models to forecast some quantity of interest y

With the **Diebold-Mariano** Test I can test if one model is predicting more accurate than another, which is cool. So I can make some 4x4 matrix and evaluate each other.

But is there any possibility to compare directly if one "benchmark" model is superior to all the other models **simultaneously**.

Thanks